# Is it possible to run an ASP.Net MVC website by hosting it as a windows service? If yes, How to achieve it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-applications, web

I need your help. I am developing a website in asp.net MVC and i need to run this website as a windows service on a server machine. Please provide me information on how to achieve it.

Comment: would you like to give a background of why do you want to do that?

Comment: I am assigned to develop a website in asp.net which needs to be hosted as a service so that it is always on and never off.

Comment: ASP.NET sites are always-ON (unless the host server goes down or IIS shuts down) - If you are looking for a "Service" which you want other applications to connect with then you should look for ASP.NET Web API - ASP.NET Web API or ASP.NET MVC/FORM Applications, They all are always-on. Read this https://www.asp.net/mvc and this https://www.asp.net/web-api - I am not sure what you want to do with Windows Service and why?